# Are notifications of Stack Overflow HTTP-only?

Tags: support, bug, ssl

The hyperlinks of comment and achievement notifications in the navigation bar are using HTTP even if I'm visiting Stack Overflow by HTTPS.

Is this something that ought to be fixed or did I miss a certain setting such as "https preferred"?

Comment: Yes, it's something to be fixed. Sometime in the next millenium, when SO offiicially and consistently properly supports ssl.

Comment: In the meantime, you could use a HTTPS everywhere browser plugin.  Which is useful beyond just SO.

Comment: @Deduplicator Rest assured that complete SSL/TLS coverage is still definitely being worked towards. For a refresher about the issues that a site like ours faces, I refer you to this meta post and the links contained within it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226032/131874

Comment: Google Chome is planning to mark sites on a http connection as unsure, like it should have been, I don't want to visit a site that shows red in my url bar.

Comment: I use HTTPS Everywhere.  Be aware that when you use it, you do not see (well, I do not see) the automatic updates such as new answers arriving or new comments being added to the question I'm looking at.  It is a nuisance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler afaik, that's an issue of how the extension manages wss connections, since the websockes works even when you are browsing on https without the extension. A bug report has been opened about the issue https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/3884

Comment: @MarkHenderson - with all due respect, the certificate problem is **non-existent** due to Let's Encrypt nowadays (you can get ANY cert for any number of domain levels). Folks cannot participate in Meta discussions over TLS without going through the hoops (Emacs, phone apps). SE is just dragging their feet behind the industry, waiting for Google to downrank HTTP.

Comment: @DeerHunter We are well aware of Google's pending changes. As for Let's Encrypt, I have a draft blog post written for blog.serverfault.com that outlines why it's great for the industry as a whole, but also those for whom it's not suitable for. The two biggest issues we face are user supplied content (breaking SSL and giving warnings in major browsers), and the lack of SNI support in a not insignificant portion of our userbase.

Comment: @MarkHenderson - would be great to read the post!

Comment: @MarkHenderson: By user-supplied content, I assume you're referring to inline images? The overwhelming majority of those on SO/SE are hosted on imgur (because that's what the built-in image uploader uses), which already supports HTTPS. A simple regexp replace to [make all imgur links protocol-relative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221304) would eliminate any mixed-content issues from about 99.9% of all posts on SO (estimate based on [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430354)).

Comment: @MarkHenderson -re SNI - should be all the IE6 installed in Lower Elbonia.

Comment: @DeerHunter Not quite. I don't have the numbers infront of me right now, but the real problem for us are Android < 2.3.6 (which dates from 2011, so  given how much penetration new Android versions get, aka not much, this is non trivial).